# Values of $\frac{e^x}{x^2+y^2}\Big(x\sin y-y\cos y-\frac{x}{e^x}\Big)$ near $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

Consider the 1-forms given by:

$w=\dfrac{e^x}{x^2+y^2}\Big((x\cos y+y\sin y)dy+(x\sin y-y\cos y)dx\Big);$

$w_0=\dfrac{-ydx}{x^2+y^2}+\dfrac{xdy}{x^2+y^2}$.

I am trying to show that $\lim_{x^2+y^2\to 0}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(w-w_0)=0$(the 1-form that vanishes everywhere). For this I decided to split the limit in two, one with respect to $dx$ and the other with respect to $dy$. They are as follow:

$\lim_{x^2+y^2\to 0}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\dfrac{e^x}{x^2+y^2}\Big(x\sin y-y\cos y-\dfrac{x}{e^x}\Big)$;

$\lim_{x^2+y^2\to 0}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\dfrac{e^x}{x^2+y^2}\Big(x\cos y+y\sin y-\dfrac{y}{e^x}\Big)$.

Both are very similar and my approach was to show that the values of
$\dfrac{e^x}{x^2+y^2}\Big(x\sin y-y\cos y-\dfrac{x}{e^x}\Big)$ are bounded near the origin but I had no success. Once this is proved I can apply the squeeze principle to compute the limit. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: First, saying "the $1$-form that vanishes everywhere" is a bit misleading. We're looking at the $1$-form *at the origin* when we take that limit. But, yes, as a form on $T_0\Bbb R^2$, it will be $0$. Second, I wouldn't divide by $e^x$. I would consider the Taylor polynomial of degree $2$ of $e^x(x\cos y+y\sin y)-x$ and then divide by $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ted Shifrin's hint solves the question. For closure's sake I will write down his hint as it already solves the problem.

Consider the Taylor polynomial of degree 2 of the function $f(x,y)=e^x(xcosy+ysiny)-x$.